# Why has my symlink stopped working? - OS X

Tags: macos, symbolic-link

A while ago I noticed my symlinks in OS X Mavericks weren't doing anything. On closer inspection, Finder was **showing them as flat files**. If I opened them in a text editor I simply saw a relative path to the original folder.

**New symlinks also had this problem**. Eventually, I removed all symlinks and have been living without them.

I have since upgraded to OS X Yosemite and created a symlink again a little while ago without problems.

Today, it's not working again. Same problem as before.

Anyone know why this might have happened, what I can do to fix it or troubleshoot?

Thanks

Comment: Still not working, lol

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS there is a definite difference between an Alias and a symbolic link (hard or soft). Though they appear same for the most part, there are some differences that may cause problems for certain applications. Symbolic links work at the file system level and should behave the same for all the applications. Aliases are created and managed at the finder level. So if you try to access them from terminal they may just appear as text files and exhibit the symptoms that you outlined above.